# Declaration Error Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, smart-contract-wallets

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract myTest2
{
    address payable owner;
    event Minted(address ownerAddress,string message);
    event transfer(address sender, string message2);

constructor () public
{
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function mint() payable external
{
    require(msg.value == 2 ether,"Not enough amount transfered to mint");
    emit Minted(msg.sender,"Minted");
}
```

The below Function gives me error:
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
function transfer(address payable recipient)payable external{
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines). The previous declaration is here:
event transfer(address sender, string message2);
^----------------------------------------------^

```
function transfer(address payable recipient)payable external{
    if(recipient == owner)
    {
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    else
    {
        recipient.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    emit transfer(msg.sender,"Transaction Successfull");
}
}
```

Comment: There's a `transfer` event, with lowercase `t`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an event and a function with the same name **transfer**, usually event starts with a capital letter so change the event declaration to this

`event Transfer(address sender, string message2);`

and then the call to

`emit Transfer(msg.sender,"Transaction Successfull");`